# Why do I get office updates for server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I was looking at updates for a Windows Server 2012R2 and noticed a bunch of office 2010 important updates. We don't have any office version on this server so wondering why these are here? Any insight is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Tim is right that any Office component can cause this. On the server in question, go to the control panel and open up the "Add/Remove Programs" tool and look for anything with the word "Office" in it.

Comment: please be sure what your doing.  Be able to restore if after your remove something , some service your offering doesnt work  But it definitely more secure, to remove anything to do with Microsoft office, and any components, services that you are not using

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Office updates don't necessarily mean a full copy of office is installed. It can just be certain components (access database connectors, deployment tools, etc) related to office.  You'll probably find a common thread if you look closer.